# Get all members of distribution list INCLUDING Mail Contacts

Tags: powershell

I have written a small powershell script to output all the members of all distribution lists (including dynamic).

```
$output = ""
$DLList = get-distributiongroup
foreach ($DL in $DLList) {
    $Dmember=get-distributiongroupmember $DL
    $Dname=$DL.name
    write-output "$Dname"
$output += "$Dname`r`n"
    foreach ($Member in $Dmember) {
        $MName=$Member.DisplayName
        write-output "-$MName"
    $output += "-$MName`r`n"
     }
     write-output ""
 $output += "`r`n"
}
$DDLList = get-dynamicdistributiongroup
foreach ($DL in $DDLList) {
    $Dmember=get-Recipient -Filter $DL.RecipientFilter
    $Dname=$DL.name
    write-output "$Dname"
$output += "$Dname`r`n"
    foreach ($Member in $Dmember) {
        $MName=$Member.DisplayName
        write-output "-$MName"
    $output += "-$MName`r`n"
    }
    write-output ""
$output += "`r`n"
}
$output | Tee-Object -file data.txt
```

This works fine except one of my DL's contains Mail Contacts. Is there a way to include them in the above script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Get-ADObject` to retrieve contacts, then you can query their `MemberOf` attribute. It's the other way around from what you want, but it works. You can use this script, just change the `-SearchBase` value to where you want to look:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Contacts, DC=domain, DC=com" \
-Properties * | ?{$_.MemberOf -ne $null} | Select DisplayName, MemberOf
```